# Jupyter Notebook Disable Autocomplete on Hinterland

Tags: jupyter-notebook, autocomplete

I know there's an extension called Hinterland responsible for the autocomplete function. Hinterland gives, most of the time, good suggestions. However it's pretty annoying when it tries to autocomplete every time I write something.

I want to deactivate the autocomplete without uninstalling the extension or disabling it. Is it possible to just get the hints?